# Call http REST api from Flink using Asynchronous I/O

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

i have to fetch data from Rest API from flink process element in every data fetch from the stream, how can i achive that, i couldnt find enough meterials to call the Rest service asynchronously. please help me with some sample articles.

Answer (score 0):

All the job is happening inside the `asyncInvoke` of the `RichAsyncFunction`. So, to be able to call REST service, You need to use some async HTTP client (technically it could be a synchronous client but this doesn't make sense). An example of async http client usage can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/async-http-client).

So, when You execute the async request all You need to do, is to  call `resultFuture.complete` in Your request handler, so that the result is passed downstream in Flink.